# Get selected item string

Tags: android, string, cursor

I have an android app where a spinner called spn2 which is filled from a database. The thing is I want to get the string of the selected item. I have tried many methods but it has not been possible, in some cases I do not get bada and other sheds some strange results, eg if I select "Maria" is the string obtained asdfe @ anssmnn718 by descir something, when I want the string is "Maria". The code is as follows:

```
   final Spinner spn2 = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spn2);      
    spn2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {  

             f = spn2.getSelectedItem().toString();

              r = String.valueOf((int)spn2.getSelectedItemId());

             obtenernombre();

          }
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> var1) {

          }
       });
```

The method get name () has the following code:

```
  private void obtenernombre() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub    

    try {

        String[] args = new String[]{r};
        baseDatos = openOrCreateDatabase(nombreBD, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null); 
        Cursor cur2 = baseDatos.rawQuery("SELECT codigo AS _id, nombre FROM contactos WHERE codigo=?", args);

        if (cur2.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                Toast.makeText( this, f, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();  
            } while (cur2.moveToNext());
        }


     } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e);
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new android developer myself, but I used several spinners in an app I developed recently, and the way I would get the text from the selected spinner item was:

```
String platformInput = platform_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I know there are other ways of doing it, but this method has worked well for me. The line uses "getSelectedItem" to grab the spinner selection and then "toString" converts it to a string. I then can work with the string in any way I need to. Hope this helps!

Mike

Comment: That line of code throws me a strange result as the example given and "Maria" does not appear

Comment: Okay. I might be missing this, but what code are you using to bind the result(s) from the database query to the spinner itself? What's the mechanism you're using to link the results to the spinner?

Comment: Clicking on the spinner should appear in the string selelccionado toast. For example if I select Maria toast should appear in the "Maria". Clicking on the spinner that is populated from a database the result is an empty string called "f" that will finally stop at toast.

Comment: Something is telling me that there is something amiss in how the spinner is being populated from the database, but, again, I am new. One thing I do see is the use of an ArrayAdapter that (I think) is normally used to bind info to the spinner (even from a database). Take a look at the following link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/   Especially look at the "loadSpinnerData" method and check out the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: The spinner is loaded without problems.

Comment: Okay. Sorry I couldn't be more help. Can anyone else help us out here?